# highcharts adding point dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, web2py

I'm trying to add a new point to highcharts line graph every 3 seconds using the following code. But it does not add the new point. 
I verified that point coming back from json was correct like [x,y]. 
Without getjson part and using a point like [3,4] it works. But when I add json it does not add the new data that was supposed to pass to json.

```
    var chart; // global        
       function requestData() {
           var series = this.series[0];

        $.getJSON('url', 
              function(point){

        // add the point

           series.addPoint(point);

        // call it again after one second

           setInterval(requestData, 3000); 

        }); 
        }
```

The way I load requestData is as follows and it works with one static point adding.

```
chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
            load: requestData
        }
```

Any idea why the function does not repeat or does not get the data or does not put he data in the point or the addpoint does not work?

I used click instead of load and it worked fine. It seems like the periodic loading does not work.

Edit: full chart code:

```
    .getJSON('url2',
    function(data){   
    $('#container11').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
            load: requestData
        }


        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'time',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            hour: '%H:%M',
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'test'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'name',
            data: data
        }]
    });
```

});

Comment: the function `requestData` is responsible for adding points to the chart but you're setting interval for `ajaxRequest`. `setInterval(ajaxRequest, 3000); ` should be `setTimeout(requestData, 3000); `. If not then posting complete code will help. How does `requestData` get `this` context inside it? Is this function part of an object?

Comment: Thanks for the that, in my code it is `requestData`, I just made a copying error. I edited the code. Actually, I tried to do `series = chart.series[0]` instead of `var series = this.series[0];` and it did not even pass a static adding point. I assume since this function is being loaded from the chart that is why `this` works. With full code you mean the rest of the chart code? I added the rest of the code in the main question

Comment: Have you seen Highcharts docs? Inside the docs you can find information how you can add point dynamically: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data

Comment: Yes, i actually used that doc to develop it. The problem is that 'load' does not seem working. Because when i use click it works. When i use click with a click it load the requestData and it loops and gets the data every 3 second as expected. But load does not seem to call requestData at all.

Comment: I got it working by bringing 'var series = this.series[0];' after 'getjson', thanks for the comments though

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by bringing 'var series = this.series[0];' after 'getjson'